# jQuery JSON and PHP Associative arrays arrays issues

Tags: php, jquery, json

Hi there I was wondering if somebody could help me?

I have the following code.  It retrieves JSON data from a php file.  The Json is the following format :

```
{"Title":"rose","Price":1.25,"Number":15},{"Title":"daisy","Price":0.75,"Number":25},{"Title":"orchid","Price":1.15,"Number":7}
```

This JSON is created using the following php code:

```
$shop = array();
$shop = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                  Price => 1.25,
                  Number => 15 
                ),
           array( Title => "daisy", 
                  Price => 0.75,
                  Number => 25,
                ),
           array( Title => "orchid", 
                  Price => 1.15,
                  Number => 7 
                )
         );

 echo json_encode($shop);
```

Whenever i try and access the data using obj.Title I get an undefined message.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.php",
        success: jsonDo
    });

    //JSON DATA = {"Title":"rose","Price":1.25,"Number":15},{"Title":"daisy","Price":0.75,"Number":25},{"Title":"orchid","Price":1.15,"Number":7}

    function jsonDo(data) {

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        alert(obj.Title)

    }
```

I was wondering how I can access the keys in the JSON and display the data?

Thanks a million.

Comment: jQuery is probably parsing the JSON for you, so `data` is already a JS object. Try `alert(data.Title);`

Comment: When in doubt, console.log()! In your case, console.log(data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"Title":"rose","Price":"1.25","Number":"15"}');

alert(obj.Title);
```

This work. Check difference in your code.

OK this is more correct:

```
var obj = [
    {"Title":"rose","Price":"1.25","Number":"15"},
    {"Title":"daisy","Price":"0.75","Number":"25"},
    {"Title":"orchid","Price":"1.15","Number":"7"}
    ];


 alert(obj[1].Title);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Except my JSON is {"Title":"rose","Price":1.25,"Number":15},{"Title":"daisy","Price":0.75,"Number":25},{"Title":"orchid","Price":1.15,"Number":7}

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that you are expecting a JSON object by informing the `dataType: "JSON"` parameter to the `ajax()` function, so you will not have to parse the data.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some PHP errors in your code. This could cause php to raise a notice / warning which might break the Json output and cause javascript to raise errors when trying to parse it.

The correct jSon output should have been

```
[{"Title":"rose","Price":1.25,"Number":15},{"Title":"daisy","Price":0.75,"Number":25},{"Title":"orchid","Price":1.15,"Number":7}]
```

Since it is in an array, the JS should be:
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.php",
        success: jsonDo
    });

```
function jsonDo(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(obj[0].Title)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use jQuery's [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method:

```
$.getJSON('data.php',function(data) {
    alert(obj.Title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try obj[0]["Title"] or obj[0].Title

dont forget that you have nested a lot of arrays and that yoyu need to access them that way again.